# Excel VBA cannot populate cells with "=("

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to dynamically populate a couple of cells in Excel with VBA with some simple formulas.

I need a formula like

```
=(B1-C2)
```

In Excel

Which is very simple to code... But I get a application or object defined error '1004'. With this simple loop.

```
For i = 1 To 3
Range("A" & i).Value = "=("
Next i
```

Therefore I tried to first declare a variable like

```
dim tmp as string
tmp = "=("

For i = 1 To 3
Range("A" & i).Value = tmp
Next i
```

But it did not work.

I have also tried to declare it as variant but with no luck.

Does anyone why this happens and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: `"=("` is not a valid formula. You're missing the rest of it... `B1-C2)`.

Comment: if you want that as a string in the cell, either format the cell as text BEFORE putting in that value, or prefix the string with `'`: `"'=("`

Comment: btw there's no loop needed, you can assign the formula e.g. via `Sheet1.Range("A1:A3").Value = ...`; instead of `.Value` it would be more evident to use `.Formula` (or `.Formula2`) as you are assigning a formula :-)